# How can I tell my table name to the laravel5 auth controller?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-5

My image is below and i am facing trouble here for more time,[image: errorImage] image tells the full story

Comment: Actual code helps a billion times more than some confusingly hard to read screenshot.

Comment: I am ambiguous that's why i posted this image.

Comment: Ambiguous is not good with questions. This screenshot is a distraction.

Comment: My Environment information is:DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test_1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: That doesn't help in the least.

Comment: Why does the `users` table not exist? If you want to rename it, you need to find the spot where you configure that. Vitthal has offered a suggestion that seems reasonable.

Comment: It is difficult to paste whole code rather than understanding pros and corns.But next time i will try to avoid image.Thanks

Comment: I am waiting for some assurance and also trying.Thanks sir.

Comment: People answering questions here would like to see the smallest amount of code relevant to the problem at hand that describes the situation you're in, as well as some explanation as to what the desired outcome is. Screenshot only questions can be very difficult for some people to answer since they're dependent on translation tools or screen readers, neither of which work very well with images.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `config/auth.php` to change the table.

'table' => 'your_table'